# Storing a column in a variable

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I wanted a formatted text to be converted into unformatted text in the UI . for that I did the following

```
        String strInput;
        String strOutput;
        strInput = txtEditorAnswer.Text;
        strOutput = Regex.Replace(strInput, "<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Trim();
        txtEditorAnswer.Text = strOutput;
        txtEditorAnswer.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(txtEditorAnswer.Text);
```

but as it changes the value in the Database also, so its creating a problem for future. Now I need to change the text after being inserted into the database.
What should I do?

Comment: Interesting question.  StackOverflow itself displays the tags in a text box, while showing a formatted preview.  Perhaps that would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case isn't clear, but I'll assume you want the "Tagged" text when the `txtEditorAnswer` has focus, and the "UnTagged" text when focus moves away.

In this case, you could attach a property to `txtEditorAnswer`, let's call it `RawText`.

On Init:

```
var text = GetTextFromDatabase();
txtEditorAnswer.RawText = text;
txtEditorAnswer.Text = Regex.Replace(text, "<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Trim();
```

On Focus:

```
txtEditorAnswer.Text = txtEditorAnswer.RawText;
```

On LostFocus:

```
txtEditorAnswer.RawText = txtEditorAnswer.Text;
SaveToDatabase(txtEditorAnswer.RawText);
txtEditorAnswer.Text = Regex.Replace(txtEditorAnswer.Text, "<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Trim();
```

(Refactor as appropriate).

Or, as @Andomar points out, you could have a second control that is your "preview" of the text being entered into `txtEditorAnswer`.